# facebook connect using javascript,html

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am working on facebook connect using javascript all is working well but im not getting the email id. This is the code i have tried

```
 http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=283313515083671&redirect_uri=http://mobile.i-xltech.com/kfbookipad/score.html?score=12&response_type=token
```

this link give the access token no and using that token no and i passed that token no through the below link:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='mytoken no'

after hitting this url i got the response from the facebook api. in response iam getting all the user details except that email ID

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with URL you trying:

1. `redirect_url` should be properly encoded (`encodeURIComponent`) so it's probably `http%3A%2F%2Fmobile.i-xltech.com%2Fkfbookipad%2Fscore.html%3Fscore%3D12`
2. You missing `scope` parameter to Authentication Endpoint (thus omitting permissions request), this should be `scope=email` so you'll be able to get user's email address.

Actually it's much easier to use Facebook JavaScript SDK ([`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)) to do most of the work for you:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      console.log('User email: ' + response.email + '.');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: i also need the facebook userid of the user which is unique how to get that

Comment: @user1350714, it's obiviously `response.id` in the same place where you can `response.email` (see example of response from [`/me`](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me))

Comment: can you give me whole code bcoz when i m using the above code i m getting no response. so please can you help me

Comment: @user1350714, You should use [JS-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and call `FB.login` after `FB.init`.